# Why are two NodeList's with similar tags not equals?

Tags: hashcode, nodelist

Don't understand why two org.w3c.dom.NodeList of one doc are not equals and them hashcodes are not equals. Although each Node inside one NodeList is equals to such Node from another NodeList?

```
    // Parse xml file to Document
    File fXmlFile = new File("src/test/resources/sample.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    // Get cais Nodes
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList caisNodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//c[@n='CAIS']/s", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList caisNodes2 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//c[@n='CAIS']/s", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    System.out.println(caisNodes.hashCode() == caisNodes2.hashCode()); //false
    System.out.println(caisNodes.equals(caisNodes2)); //false
    for (int i = 0; i < caisNodes.getLength(); i++) {
System.out.println(caisNodes.item(i).equals(caisNodes2.item(i))); // all true 
System.out.println(caisNodes.item(i).hashCode()==caisNodes2.item(i).hashCode()); // all true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to compare two objects, you are comparing references, not values. Both of these exists in different places inside the memory and have different addresses. Thus, when you apply equality operator on them, it returns false.
I-E 0xA332CD == 0xB2254F // false

Comment: Doesn't NodeList have an equals and hashcode method override?

Comment: Yes, but again equals method checks based on value rather than reference.

Comment: As I understand, in my case I apply '==' operator to primitive type int (comparing values, not references) and apply equals method to objects, that should have overwritten  method 'equals'